# Alternative to @CSVbindbyname to each for member of pojo

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv

I have 100 fields in my POJO. I need to specify @CSVbindbyname  annotation above each pojo data member . Any alternative to this? Thanks for your time.

BTW this is the code I am following. https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/csv-msg-converter.html

```
protected void writeInternal(L t, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
     HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<T> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<>();
     strategy.setType(toBeanType(t.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()));
      OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(outputMessage.getBody());
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        StatefulBeanToCsv<T> beanToCsv =
                  new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(outputStream)
                            .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                            .withMappingStrategy(strategy)      
                            .withOrderedResults(true)
                            .build();
        try {
            beanToCsv.write(t.getList());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
}
```

And here is the POJO:

```
public class Customer {

    @Id

    @CsvBindByName
    Long ID;

    @CsvBindByName
    String NAME;

    @CsvBindByName
    String EMAIL;

    . . .
}
```

Comment: Hi -- can you add a short code sample that show the problem to save us having to follow a link to who-knows-where?  Thanks!

Comment: I just added Jay

Comment: Have you looked at: https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-opencsv/

Comment: They seem to be using csvbindbyposition and csvbindbyname? I was asking for an alternative

Comment: Did you get to the part on mapping strategies?

Comment: Sorry and thanks. Will look into it and will reply back